# Select constant in JOOQ union

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I need to do the equivalent of this in JOOQ.

```
SELECT
  name,
  'companyType' AS resultType
FROM company
UNION ALL
SELECT
  name,
  'userType' AS resultType
FROM "user";
```

I have figured out how to do unionall in JOOQ fine but I cannot figure out how to select a constant value for results in either select of the union.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're looking for [`DSL.inline()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#inline-java.lang.String-), which is used for precisely this:

```java
inline("companyType").as("resultType")
```

Or, the full query:

```java
using(configuration)
  .select(COMPANY.NAME, inline("companyType").as("resultType"))
  .from(COMPANY)
  .unionAll(
   select(USER.NAME, inline("userType").as("resultType"))
  .from(USER))
  .fetch();
```

Both examples assume you have this static import:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

More information can be found here: http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/inlined-parameters

Comment: Why not use DSL.val("companyType").as("resultType") and get the benefit of bind variables?

Comment: @AmitGoldstein: Well, what exactly *is* the benefit of a bind variable, specifically in this case? 1) The OP didn't seem to want bind values. Look at the title, it says *"constant"*, 2) there are many cases where bind values are actually the wrong choice. This particular example (union discriminators) is one of them. More info: https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/28/10-cool-sql-optimisations-that-do-not-depend-on-the-cost-model/ (look at item 10, predicate pushdown for a related example), or https://blog.jooq.org/2017/05/30/when-to-use-bind-values-and-when-to-use-inline-values-in-sql/

Comment: Such a great read, and also the comment section, I learned so much - thank you!